# Error on Lambda nested Sets in java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to achieve the same using lambda expressions but getting error

```
for (String id:ids) {
    for (MainGrid ms:grids) {
        for (GridRep innerGrid: ms.getInnerGrid()){
            if(innerGrid.getId().equals(id)){
                finalGrid.add(innerGrid);
                break;
            }
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

The above code in lambda

```
for (String id:ids) {
    finalGrid.add(grids.stream().flatMap(ms -> ms.getInnerGrid().stream())
                   .filter(s -> s.getId().equals(id)).findFirst().get());
}
```

Error: The same works while using the traditional for(), Can someone kindly guide me how to achieve the same using lambda or if there is some miss in my code

> 31-Jan-2018 11:38:29.221 SEVERE [http-apr-9910-exec-8]
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service()
>   for servlet [Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet] in context with path
>   [/lineManagement] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested
>   exception is java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present] with
>   root cause
>        java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present   at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)

Comment: Are you actually using the LambdaJ library? Or just Java 8's built-in lambdas?

Comment: java 8 built in lambda

Comment: `grids.stream()
                .flatMap(mainGrid -> mainGrid.getInnerGrid().stream())
                         .filter(gridRep -> ids.contains(gridRep.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Why does your outer loop break unconditionally?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Stream.findFirst()` returns an empty optional if the stream is empty, in which case calling `get()` results in an exception. The simplest solution is to use `ifPresent()` instead:

```
grids.stream()
        .flatMap(ms -> ms.getInnerGrid().stream())
        .filter(s -> s.getId().equals(id))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(finalGrid::add);
```

Comment: You're welcome. If this solved your problem, please [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 0):

I think that your code will fail if at any moment an element is not found. Could you try this?:

```
for (String id:ids) {
    Optional optional = grids.stream().flatMap(ms -> ms.getInnerGrid().stream())
        .filter(s -> s.getId().equals(id)).findFirst();
    if (optional.isPresent())
        finalGrid.add(optional.get());
}
```

Of course, set the type of the Optional correctly.

Comment: Thanks! Yes that was the issue when the element was empty. Both the solutions worked.

Comment: I have to admit that I like shmosel's answer better because he explained about the Optional and because he used ifPresent.